# How to make two threads take turns executing their respective critical sections after one thread ends

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

In modern C++ with STL threads I want to have two worker threads that take turns doing their work. Only one can be working at a time and each may only get one turn before the other takes a turn. I have this part working.
The added constraint is that one thread needs to keep taking turns after the other thread finishes. But in my code the remaining worker thread deadlocks after the first worker thread finishes. I don't understand why, given that the last things the first worker did was unlock and notify the condition variable, which should've woken the second one up. Here's the code:

```
{
    std::mutex mu;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    int turn = 0;

    auto thread_func = [&](int tid, int iters) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
        lk.unlock();

        for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
            lk.lock();
            cv.wait(lk, [&] {return turn == tid; });

            printf("tid=%d turn=%d i=%d/%d\n", tid, turn, i, iters);
            fflush(stdout);

            turn = !turn;
            lk.unlock();
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    };

    auto th0 = std::thread(thread_func, 0, 20);
    auto th1 = std::thread(thread_func, 1, 25); // Does more iterations

    printf("Made the threads.\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    th0.join();
    th1.join();

    printf("Both joined.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

I don't know whether this is something I don't understand about concurrency in STL threads, or whether I just have a logic bug in my code. Note that there is a question on SO that's similar to this, but without the second worker having to run longer than the first. I can't find it right now to link to it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: When two threads are using the same mutex to synchronise, the only guarantee is that only one thread will have the mutex locked at one time.   There is no guarantee that, when thread A releases, that thread B will succeed in locking.  If you want such a sequence, then you need to implement it yourself.   That means both threads must cooperate in keeping track of which thread had the lock last, and each thread must check which thread had the lock last, and release immediately if the other is still running and didn't have the most recent lock.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering, though, if there is no guarantee that threads can ever succeed in locking then how is forward progress ever ensured in any code that uses mutexes? Someone could write single-threaded code with a mutex and it could deadlock when grabbing the mutex. Also, what does notify_all mean if not wake up the threads and cause them to start executing?

Comment: that needs to be addressed in design of the (code in the) threads, how they share data, and how they synchronise.  When a thread releases a mutex, there is some probability that another thread that is attempting to grab (or subsequently attempts to grab) the mutex will succeed.  But there is no guarantee on which thread will succeed first.   Practically, if you have code that relies on particular sequencing, it might be better putting the relevant sections of code into one thread, and execute them sequentially (e.g. a loop that does A then B, and repeats).

Comment: That sort of lock-step execution means you really aren't using threads.

Comment: Maybe it means that I don't *have* to use threads, but you can clearly see that I *am* using threads. The case I am modeling here is actually one where there are two worker threads that exist for other reasons, off in different parts of the code doing different things. Then for a while they come together and have to do this lock-step work. During the lock-step I agree that the more obvious implementation is to just do A then B, then repeat. But that doesn't work in the broader context of the two threads.

Answer (score 0):

When one thread is done, the other will wait for a notification that nobody will send. When only one thread is left, you need to either stop using the condition variable or signal the condition variable some other way.

Comment: Hmmm.... Why do you say it's waiting for a notification that nobody will send? It sends it with cv.notify_all(). On all of the other iterations this succeeded in waking up the other thread. Why does it not do so this time?

Comment: The second thread was sending it to the first, now the second thread is gone.